# Spring Boot REST display id of parent only in a JSON response

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot

Assume I have the following class:

```
public class ChildEntity {

   ...

   @ManyToOne
   private ParentEntity parent;  

   ...

}
```

Now, I have  a REST endpoint that retrieves a child entity object from the database, thus my JSON is the following:

```
{"id": "123", "name":"someName", "parent": { //parent fields here } ... }
```

I want to format my JSON responses in another way. I want parent display only the id from the database, instead of the whole object:

```
{"id": "123", "name":"someName", "parentId": "1" ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically returning entities directly from endpoints isn't a good idea. You make very tight coupling between DB model and responses. Instead, implement a POJO class that will be equivalent of the HTTP response you sent.

This POJO will have all `ChildEntity` fields and `parentId` only and will be constructed in *HTTP* layer.

Please, see the discussion in comments, basically such an object returned from web layer is not a DTO according to me.

Comment: Please mention DTO/TO somewhere.

Comment: Basically I don't think it's a DTO/VO/TO. These kind of objects should be used internally between the layers of application, not to be returned to the end user. As in this asrticle: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/understanding-spring-web-application-architecture-the-classic-way/

Comment: Yeah, according to the article you linked such an object is called DTO. "If we expose our domain model to the outside world, we cannot change it without breaking the other stuff that depends from it. If we use DTOs, we can change our domain model as long as we don’t make any changes to the DTOs." Imo objects used to transfer data between boundaries (may it be IPC or REST) are (D)TOs.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I always used such objects to pass them between layers as I said. Objects exposed to outside world are typically called with `*Res` or `*Req` suffixes.

Comment: Thank you Opal. Btw, do DTO objects affect the performance? Recreating a new object from another object sounds costly, I am not sure though

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't bother till it will turn out that this may be a real performance problem. You can use a mapper, such as dozzer if you really need id. It also definitely depends on how such project is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I am annotating @JsonIgnore which ever field I do not want to be part of JSON response. Creating parallel POJO for each entity is costly affair.

```
@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@Column(name="DELETED")
private boolean deleted = false;
```